# Docker fails to load container after power outage. How to remove corrupted containers?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, containers

Couple of my docker containers got messed up due power outage and as a results Docker daemon fails to start. I would like save healthy containers and only remove few corrupted ones.

Is this possible to achieve by removing some container and database files manually?

Dockerd dębug modę reports:

```
ERRO[2020-11-19T09:38:00.148463604+02:00] Failed to load container 4797b563d2a2c8898ec9246d9262defcfc205dc0d7669eaea94f48f678dad286: invalid character '.' looking for beginning of value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove docker containers by using the `docker rm <CONTAINER ID|NAME>` command.

If you need to find the container id, `docker container ls -a` will display all containers and the id is in the first column.